# React and Redux: create store methods

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to Redux. What are all methods we can use to create a Redux store in a React application?

Answer (score 1):

The Redux store API is tiny and has only four methods:

- `store.getState()` - Returns the current state object tree.
- `store.dispatch(action)` - Dispatch an action to change the state.
- `store.subscribe(listener)` - Listen to changes in the state tree.
- `store.replaceReducer(nextReducer)` - Replaces the current reducer with another.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to construct a Redux store in a React application. The most prevalent techniques are listed below:

1. Using the `createStore()` function: The most straightforward way to create a Redux store is to use the `createStore()` function provided by the Redux library. This method requires you to define a root reducer function that combines all your reducers and passes it to the `createStore()` function as an argument.

   Here is an example:

   ```
   import { createStore } from 'redux';
   import rootReducer from './reducers';

   const store = createStore(rootReducer);
   ```
2. Using the `configureStore()` function: The `configureStore()` function is a helper function provided by the Redux Toolkit that simplifies the process of creating a Redux store. It includes several opinionated defaults and best practices to help you set up your store quickly.

   Here is an example:

   ```
   import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
   import rootReducer from './reducers';

   const store = configureStore({
     reducer: rootReducer,
   });
   ```
3. Using the Provider component: Once you have created a Redux store, you need to make it available to your React components. The recommended way to do this is to use the Provider component provided by the *react-redux* library.

   Here is an example:

   ```
   import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
   import store from './store';

   ReactDOM.render(
     <Provider store={store}>
       <App />
     </Provider>,
     document.getElementById('root')
   );
   ```

In this example, we are wrapping our root component (in this case, <App />) with the Provider component and passing our store as a prop.

These are only a handful of the techniques available to you when building a Redux store for a React application. You could decide to employ other techniques or unique combinations based on your own requirements and preferences.